# How to setup breadcrumbs on a community

Tags: community

Is it possible to setup breadcrumbs on a community. I see some documentation in the SLDS document but haven't found any details of how to get it working.

Comment: When you say community ?Is it using templates or vf

Answer (score 1):

SLDS has nothing to do with Communities except for styling.

Until Communities adds a native component for breadcrumbing, you will have to implement a custom lightning component.

Comment: Are breadcrumbs still not available on a community page? I don't see 'Page Elements' on community builder page to add breadcrumbs

Answer (score 0):

From the Salesforce Knowledge Article

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=siteforce_breadcrumb_add.htm&type=5

> Add a Breadcrumb page element to your page to help users navigate
>   through your site and show the page’s location in the site hierarchy.
>
> - Open the page or page template that you want to add the breadcrumb    element to.
> - Drag a Breadcrumb from the Page Elements pane onto the    page.
> - In the Properties pane, under Root, specify a custom root node    for the breadcrumb. By default, the root value is set to None, which
>     builds the breadcrumb structure based on the page’s location in the
>     site map.    Select Home Page to set the site’s home page as the first
>     item in the breadcrumb. To find out how to set a site’s home page,
>     see Configuring Site Properties.    Select a specific site page to set
>     it as the first item in the breadcrumb. Note NOTE You can’t set a
>     site map link as a custom root node in a breadcrumb.
> - In the Properties pane, under Separator, you can customize the separator    used between breadcrumb nodes. By default, the separator
>     is >.    However, you can change it to another text symbol or insert
>     HTML code    for an image in your site, such as .
> - To style the breadcrumb:    Click the Style pane and ensure Class is selected.    Choose an option from the Style drop-down list.
>     Adjust the values in the Visual tab as desired.